# Can0 return no data, but with no error

Tags: can, serial-bus, db9

I'm actually trying to get data from a CAN on vehicle connected by DB9 on my raspberry. The DB9 provides also energy to the raspberry ([here the material that i'm using](https://copperhilltech.com/content/PICAN3_UGA_10.pdf)).

I've followed every of these instructions:

1. Change /boot/config.txt by adding those lines:

```
   dtparam=spi=on
   dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=25
   dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay
```

2. After reboot, create the CAN interface:

```
   sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```

3. Connect the PiCAN to a CAN-BUS network, and listen to it:

```
   candump can0
```

If I open an other tab in my terminal and sending a message with `cansend can0 7DF#0201050000000000`, the message will appear on the first tab that is listening. But I got nothing from the vehicle.

Here is what I see if I do an "ifconfig":

```
can0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 16
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 10  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

For context, I'm more a dev than an engineer, I wonder if the DB9 can send me information and provides me energy at the same times. Also I tried to put the raspberry on a simple battery (without vehicle), and the strangest thing was that the can0 device was still there.

Anyone knows what I did wrong?

Kind regards,

Comment: "I wonder if the DB9 can send me information and provides me energy at the same times" If you are using one of the common OBD interfaces. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics. Standard CAN DB9 pin-out has an optional supply pin intended for powering secondary side of galvanic isolation, but it's sometimes used for other supplies too.

Comment: Also, it's pretty much impossible to do any form of CAN development without knowing the protocol used and also using an analyser/sniffer tool.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I'm using the PiCan 3, the protocol is the european one for CAN vehicle (one frame = ID + clock + CRC + frame). The bus speed is 500kbps.

Comment: That's just the data link layer, it doesn't say jack about the payload. By "protocol" I mean the application tier.

Comment: hmm, in the features linked in the post, it says "his PiCAN2 board provide CAN-Bus capability for the Raspberry Pi 4. It uses the Microchip MCP2515 CAN controller with MCP2551 CAN transceiver. Connection are made via DB9", also the driver is "SocketCAN". In a python example, it says to do :
`can.interface.Bus(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan_native')`

Comment: That's not very useful info, though likely it's a CAN standard DB9 pinout then. Check the signals with your oscilloscope. As for protocols, all the socket-this-and-that is irrevant, see the link I posted https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#OBD-II_signal_protocols.

Comment: My bad for the misunderstanding, the protocol used is the fifth one in the link you've posted, the "ISO 15765 CAN" by Bosch.